# Is there a way to seek in an Avro Python?

Tags: avro

After writing a number of Avro records and storing their file offsets via [DataFileWriter.sync](https://github.com/venmo/python3-avro/blob/master/avro/datafile.py#L310), I'd like to be able to read the record at a particular offset.

The documentation for DataFileWriter.sync states:

> Return the current position as a value that may be passed to
> DataFileReader.seek(long)

But this seems incorrect as DataFileReader has no method named seek. I am using the Avro Python library version 1.11.1.

Comment: I think it's only possible with fastavro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeking the underlying file object works.

```
def read(path, offset):
    with DataFileReader(open(path, 'rb'), DatumReader()) as reader:
        reader.reader.seek(offset)
        result = next(reader)
        return result
```